# D6 Views field-override.tpl.php - [field] tokens not getting overridden output?

Tags: drupal, view, themes, url-rewriting

I created a theme override file for all instances of one of my CCK fields, "tags."

I'm excluding most of the fields in my view, and combining them using `[field_tokens]` in the last fields in the view, so I can easily format my output in one field. Example:

[✓] Rewrite the output of *Global: Custom Text*:

`<div>[field_1]: You're viewing my [tags] <strong>work</strong>!</div>`

However, my override theme field template file is **not** kicking in for `[tags]` unless I uncheck the checkbox "Exclude from display."

In other words, the field is only overridden when it is output normally in its own Views-native, separate field, and *not* wherever the field's `[tags]` token is used.

Is this a Views glitch? I'm sure I've overridden fields before using .tpl files and the `$output` has been rewritten everywhere the tokens are used...

Can anyone explain?